# Interpreting the Bockstein lemma?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I am reading through "Cohomology Operations and Applications in Homotopy Theory" by Mosher and Tangora and I had a little bit of confusion with the Bockstein lemma.  All cohomology will be with $\mathbb{Z}/2$-coefficients.  The map $d_i$ is the $i$-th Bockstein differential and the map $\tau$ is the transgression in the Serre spectral sequence.  The statement of the lemma is as follows, suppose that $F \to E \to B$ is a fibration with maps $j: F \to E$ and $p: E \to B$ and let $i \geq 1$ be an integer.  Let $u \in H^n(F)$ is transgressive and $d_i v = \tau (u)$.  Then the Bockstein lemma says that $d_{i+1} p^\ast(v)$ is defined and $j^\ast d_{i+1} p^\ast(v) = d_1(u)$.

The authors say that "The equalities should be suitably interpreted." and I wanted to see if I am doing that correctly, namely the last equality.  In particular, when they write $j^\ast d_{i+1} p^\ast(v)$ does that mean that I should take a lift of $d_{i+1} p^\ast(v)$ to $H^{n+1}(E)$, apply $j^\ast$ to that lift, and then interpret the result in $H^{n+1}(F)$?  So the equality $j^\ast d_{i+1} p^\ast(v) = d_1(u)$ is an equality of elements in $H^{n+1}(F)$?

Why does $j^\ast d_{i+1} p^\ast(v)$ not depend on the choice of lift of $d_{i+1} p^\ast(v)$ to $H^{n+1}(E)$?